# How to completely exclude sub-rule from managed rule in AWS WAF v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I trying to implement WAF protection at AWS and using WAS WAF v2.

What I need:

1. Add custom responses when request is blocked
2. Exclude payload body size check (`SizeRestrictions_BODY`) from `AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet` rule
3. Block request if any other check is positive

What I tried:

Here is JSON of my example WEB ACL:

```json
{
  "Name": "example",
  "Id": "uuiduuid-uuid-uuid-uuiduuid",
  "ARN": "arn:aws:wafv2:ap-northeast-1:0123456789:regional/webacl/example/uuiduuid-uuid-uuid-uuiduuid",
  "DefaultAction": {
    "Allow": {}
  },
  "Description": "WAF example",
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Name": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList",
      "Priority": 0,
      "Statement": {
        "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
          "VendorName": "AWS",
          "Name": "AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
        }
      },
      "OverrideAction": {
        "Count": {}
      },
      "VisibilityConfig": {
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": false,
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
        "MetricName": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet",
      "Priority": 1,
      "Statement": {
        "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
          "VendorName": "AWS",
          "Name": "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet",
          "ExcludedRules": [
            {
              "Name": "SizeRestrictions_BODY"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "OverrideAction": {
        "Count": {}
      },
      "VisibilityConfig": {
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": false,
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
        "MetricName": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "BlockLabeledRequests",
      "Priority": 2,
      "Statement": {
        "OrStatement": {
          "Statements": [
            {
              "LabelMatchStatement": {
                "Scope": "NAMESPACE",
                "Key": "awswaf:managed:aws:"
              }
            },
            {
              "NotStatement": {
                "Statement": {
                  "LabelMatchStatement": {
                    "Scope": "LABEL",
                    "Key": "awswaf:managed:aws:core-rule-set:SizeRestrictions_Body"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "Action": {
        "Block": {
          "CustomResponse": {
            "ResponseCode": 499,
            "CustomResponseBodyKey": "custom-response-body",
            "ResponseHeaders": [
              {
                "Name": "x-custom-header",
                "Value": "hello-world"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "VisibilityConfig": {
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": false,
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
        "MetricName": "BlockLabeledRequests"
      }
    }
  ],
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": false,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "waf-example"
  },
  "Capacity": 727,
  "ManagedByFirewallManager": false,
  "LabelNamespace": "awswaf:0123456789:webacl:example:",
  "CustomResponseBodies": {
    "custom-response-body": {
      "ContentType": "APPLICATION_JSON",
      "Content": "{\n  \"error\": \"oops, something wrong\"\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

What is happening here:

1. Request go through `AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList` rule. If this check is not passed (positive) `awswaf:managed:aws:rule-set-name:rule-name` label will be added.
2. Because of default action overridden to `Count` request go to next rule in any way. (Why I can't block bad request immediately? Because default block action of the rule returning standard response, but I have to customize it. And that is not possible to override `Block` response. Only `Count` may be overridden. And that is stupid limitation N1.)
3. Request go through `AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet` rule and even if `SizeRestrictions_BODY`'s action overridden to `Count`, the rule still adding own label `awswaf:managed:aws:core-rule-set:SizeRestrictions_Body` to request but not blocks it (It is not possible to disable rule at all, at least `Count` should be triggered. Stupid limitation N2.)
4. Rule set action overridden to `Count`, so request goes to final rule
5. Final rule `BlockLabeledRequests` checks if any label starting from `awswaf:managed:aws:`  exists in request and blocks it if YES. But `SizeRestrictions_Body` adding own label starting from `awswaf:managed:aws:` and that makes impossible to use `awswaf:managed:aws:` existence check. Because of it I set two conditions: Request will be blocked if has label starting from `awswaf:managed:aws:` or doesn't have label `awswaf:managed:aws:core-rule-set:SizeRestrictions_Body`. In most cases it working correct, but if we add to request big sized payload `SizeRestrictions_Body` will be triggered and request will be passed even if we have another rules triggered, and that is a security hole. WAF if statements logic is pretty dumb and only one possible way to exclude `SizeRestrictions_Body` is to check all `awswaf:managed:aws:rule-set-name:rule-name` one by one with `if and` statement and exclude `SizeRestrictions_Body` from it. But it is inconvenient because number of rules is pretty big. (stupid limitation N3.)

**QUESTION:** So is here any way to set thing `What I need` by any another logic? Or just exclude only `awswaf:managed:aws:core-rule-set:SizeRestrictions_Body` label check but use wildcard label check `awswaf:managed:aws:` at same time? Or may be here is some way to force remove `awswaf:managed:aws:core-rule-set:SizeRestrictions_Body` label from request before label checking?

AWS WAF limitations making it pretty useless